# How to route email from unauthorized address to a specific email address?

Tags: email, bounce-management

I'm working on a requirement where we receive emails from external system and process information from the same and create records in SF . I have setup an email service with handler class and it works fine apart from the fact that it doesn't respect the settings for routing emails sent from unauthorized addresses (any email address not present on Email Service 'Accept Email From' considered as unauthorized).

I'd like to track emails coming from unauthorized email addresses and have them routed to a specific user in SF.

Verified below settings by sending email from my personal email(unauthorized) to the email service address and it didn't route the email to the specific email address mentioned under 'Failure Response Settings'.

[image]

Am I missing any particular setting?

Comment: Account Email From is an optional field.

Comment: @identigral Yes it is , if left blank then the email service accepts email from any address, if filled in then it is supposed to accept emails from the specified addresses right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email was not being sent due to the Email Deliverability setting set to 'System email only'. Changed to 'All Email' and also checked 'Activate Bounce Management' checkbox on the Deliverability settings. Now any email from unauthorized address is being routed to the email-id mentioned on 'Route Error Emails to This Email Address' at the Email Service.